# Aligning buttons with form element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a search bar with drop down and two buttons. All of them have a form element within them. This is distorting their alignment which is otherwise proper. What am I missing? Screenshot of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwRvJ.jpg

Code:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <form method="POST" action="searchcategory.php" class = "col-sm-8">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <button type="button" name="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#sup_cat" data-value="sup_cat">Super Category</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#cat" data-value="cat">Category</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sub1" data-value="sub1">Sub Category 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sub2" data-value="sub2">Sub Category 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bar" placeholder="Search term...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
           </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
  <a href="addtree.php" class= "btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> ADD</span></a></form>
  <a href="uploadtree.php" class= "btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open" aria-hidden="true"> UPLOAD</span></a>  
  <a href="downloadtree.php" class= "btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"> DOWNLOAD</span></a>
   <form method ="POST" action = "category.php">
     <button class=" btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> DELETE</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what's missing there. But you are missing your code in the question. Post it please, so that we can help.

Comment: Can you place your code here.

Comment: Hi - Added the code.

Comment: How are they supposed to be lined up? Horizontally under the search bar? And are there supposed to be two separate forms in this because the second one isn't closed anywhere.

Comment: @vanburenx Yes. Horizontally inline with the search bar. My mistake. In the actual code, the form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the rest of your page is structured this may help. It's hard to tell, so if possible you should post all your code related to the problem.

```css
.search-panel,
.content {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .input-group .btn-group-justified button,
  form button.btn-danger {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <form method="POST" action="searchcategory.php">
        <div class="input-group search-panel">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" name="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span>  <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#sup_cat" data-value="sup_cat">Super Category</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#cat" data-value="cat">Category</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#sub1" data-value="sub1">Sub Category 1</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#sub2" data-value="sub2">Sub Category 2</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param" />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bar" placeholder="Search term..." /> <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> ADD</span>

              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open" aria-hidden="true"> UPLOAD</span>

              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"> DOWNLOAD</span>

              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form method="POST" action="category.php">
        <button class=" btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> DELETE</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="content">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
        College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
        and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```